# C subarrays delete unexpectedly instead of when supposed to

Tags: arrays, c, iteration, sdl

I'm currently writing a game in C and SDL2. In the game, random walls will spawn on each side of the screen, leaving a small gap for the player to fit through. If the player hits a wall, the game is over. Here's a sketch of what I want the game to look like at the end:

[image: Sketch of the end goal for my game]

I'm currently working on side-scrolling. The two-dimensional array `grid` contains up to 255 arrays consisting of X and Y co-ordinates for a block on the grid. For example,

`[[0,5],[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[6,5],[7,5],[8,5],[9,5]]`

Would create two walls at Y co-ordinate 5 with a gap between X co-ordinate 3 and 6.

The plan for side-scrolling in my game is for any block on the grid with a Y co-ordinate of below -30 (30 being the size of a block) gets deleted and all other subarrays are shifted one to the left and the values of the furthest right one are set to null so it can be used again. Rows are generated every six spaces.

However, every few rows of walls, all the walls suddenly just vanish. Here is a video of this happening: https://youtu.be/Sb8XTU6zE3Y

Here is the relevant code:

```
float grid[GRID_MAX_ITEMS][2]; // GRID_MAX_ITEMS is 255

void delete_grid_space(int index) { // Delete block from grid array by index
    // Move each array in grid to the left
    for (int i = get_grid_length(); i > index; i--) {
        grid[i-1][0] = grid[i][0];
        grid[i-1][1] = grid[i][1];
    }

    // Delete the original array in grid by the index
    grid[index][0] = '\0';
    grid[index][1] = '\0';

}

void move_grid_down(float change) { // Move all blocks in grid down by given decimal
    int number_indexes_deleted = 0; // Number of blocks deleted from grid so we have the right index

    for (int i = 0; i < get_grid_length(); i++) { // Go through all blocks in grid
        int index = i - number_indexes_deleted; // Get index accounting for any deleted blocks
        grid[index][1] -= change; // Subtract change from block Y
        if (grid[index][1] < -GRID_SPACE_SIZE) { // If Y is below negative grid space size (30), it is not visible anymore and has no use
            delete_grid_space(index); // Delete the block using its index
            number_indexes_deleted++; // Increment the number of indexes deleted
        }
    }

    if (GRID_ROWS - grid[get_grid_length() - 1][1] >= 6) { // If it has been 6 spaces since a row last generated
        add_row(GRID_ROWS + 1); // Add a new row
    }
}

void update(SDL_Renderer *renderer) { // Update every frame
    ...
    move_grid_down((float)7 / FRAME_TARGET_TIME); // FRAME_TARGET_TIME is equal to the number of milliseconds to wait inbetween frames

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { // Main function
    ...
    init_grid(); // Initialise grid

    running = true; // Game is running

    ...
    while (running) {
        update(renderer); // Update the screen
        ...
    }

}
```

I edited the code to print out the size of `grid` every time a new row is added. I notice despite rows going off the screen, the length still gets bigger, until it reaches 64 at which point all blocks disappear from the screen and the length then reverts to 8. Here's the video: https://youtu.be/2c7FK5XE9mg

```
if (GRID_ROWS - grid[get_grid_length() - 1][1] >= 6) { // If it has been 6 spaces since a row last generated
    add_row(GRID_ROWS + 1); // Add a new row
    printf("%d\n", get_grid_length());
}
```

This suggests despite the Y values of the blocks in the `grid` array going below -30 they are not being deleted. However, that doesn't explain the unexpected disappearing. If anyone could help me understand why the rows suddenly vanish I would appreciate it.

Comment: In `delete_grid_space()` I don't think you should be doing that "Delete the original..." bit - you're overwriting the last (lowest index) element that you just moved with null characters.

Comment: Oh, you seem to be right, I should be deleting the furthest right block. I'll try changing that later and let you know if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

The part with `// Delete the original array in grid by the index` comment causes it probably. I wouldn't move a null character into a float array even if it somehow gets implicitly casted into float.

Also you could store the values as a struct like:

```cpp
typedef struct{
  float x;
  float y;
} Vector2;
```

That would make it easier to handle coordinates.